# Google spreadsheet formula for value/row id return

Tags: google-sheets

I have an excel for test cases with 3 columns across some 200 rows, i'm in need of a formula to compare two columns of 'priority' and 'result' where if values 'P0' and 'Fail' match, its to return the third adjacent column's value or even the row id back, can any one please provide a solution for this or hint at it if possible, much appreciated!

Sample data with columns say, A,B and C. Would like to know if Result and Priority can be compared for **P0** and **Fail** and all adjacent row contents in **Test Case** can be returned to another cell(s).

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nNAk.jpg)

Comment: Add a sample of the input data, the expected result and a description of your research and attempts to solve this.

Comment: Added sample data, haven't tried much except one or two attempts with 'index' and couldnt get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=FILTER(A2:A,B2:B="FAIL",C2:C="P0")
```

Comment: thanks, this worked just fine, could you explain the formula if you dont mind, im not sure what range is considered here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You might also try IF and AND functions per cell in an adjacent column of the one you are reviewing.

## Code

=if(and(b2="fail",c2="p0"),"error","")

## Explination

I like to leave blank cells that do not match. Simply put this in a column adjacent - say column D - and fill. The provided code also allows you to see for possible trends.